# Error in creating heap object for the managed "ref class"

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

I am getting a "undeclared identifier" error in creating the object for managed "ref class" in C++.

```
ProfileClrApp ^profiler = gcnew ProfileClrApp();
```

The error is

> Error 4   error C2065: 'ProfileClrApp' : undeclared
>   identifier    D:\MixedModeProfiler_src\DiagProfiler\DiagProfilerConsole\DiagProfilerConsole.cpp   88  1   DiagProfilerConsole

And i am compiling the code with /clr option only in VS2012.

What could be the issue..?

-Rahul Jain

Comment: That's impossible to say when you don't give more information. You may want to start with posting Error 1.

Comment: Please let me know what are the other info u need.. ?? u need the definition of the class or version of .Net framework ?? .. Version of .Net framwork is 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"undeclared identifier" means that the typename has not been introduced; that `ProfileClrApp` is not a type in the current scope. Have you included the correct headers?

Comment: I have included now and that error has gone. Now i am getting another set of errors  " >DiagProfilerConsole.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003) ProfileClrApp::StartProcess" . (posting one error).

Comment: I am compiling the sample code taken in [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/384514/Building-a-Mixed-Mode-Sampling-Profiler?msg=4866176#xx4866176xx)

Comment: I've never used your compiler but it looks like a linker error.  You probably need to link to the library file that contains the function definition it is asking for